# 2016 AIME #7 - the controversy?

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math

Here's the problem

> For integers $a$ and $b$ consider the complex number
>   $$\frac{\sqrt{ab+2016}}{ab+100} -
>  \left(\frac{\sqrt{|a+b|}}{ab+100}\right)i$$ Find the number of
>   ordered pairs of integers $(a, b)$ such that this complex number is a
>   real number.

So on the [AoPS thread](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h1207196_complex_is_real) there are two opinions.

The basic solution goes somewhat like this.

If $a+b=0$ and $ab+2016 \ge 0$, there are $87$ pairs since we need to not count $(10,-10)$ and $(-10,10)$.

If $a+b \not= 0$ and the first term cancels out complex part, we would have $ab+2016<0$ and $ab+2016=a+b$ or $ab+2016=-a-b$. We can find $16$ solutions here.

Now the controversy comes in. Some people claim that the answer must be $87$, since (this is how I understood it) for example $\sqrt{-4}$ can be either $2i$ or $-2i$.

[See here for one explanation.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h1207196p5971618) [See here for another.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c5h1207196p5969037)

So I would like to ask, what would be correct?

Comment: What is correct is a matter of what the definition of $\sqrt{x}$ is taken to be. By far the most common definition is that $\sqrt{-4}$ means the [principal square root](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalSquareRoot.html) $2i$ (see also [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers)) just as $\sqrt{4}$ is defined to be $2$ and not $-2$.